# Import CSV with data sections with BCP,BULK Insert or openrowdataset

Tags: sql, bulkinsert, bcp

I have a CSV file in following format which I wish to import in SQL table.

I have a working solution for a straight CSV like

## header

Column
Rows

## footer

But  now I want to import following structure

## header

Column
Rows

## footer

## header

Column
Rows

## footer

## header

Column
Rows

## footer

## header

Column
Rows

## footer

I have also created a format file but it doesn't help as each section belongs to a separate table in the SQL database.

I'm using SQL 2008 R2.

Please help regarding this as I can't see any light.

Comment: If I were you, I'd be tackling this with SSIS rather than directly with SQL.

Comment: Thats the problem. I'm restricted to use stored procedure only.

Comment: Wow, that sucks. That makes life a lot trickier...

Comment: No Its not that bad. At least we'll learn a new trick.

Comment: Are the data formats different in each group?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear - is the structure of the data for each group identical? i.e., assuming we have the problem of how solved, could it all go into one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved now.

I have created a stored procedure which extracts all data in single column and then loops it in CTE to split the data.

The stored procedure is somewhat huge to post it here, but if anyone wants it I can provide sample file and procedure.